# How to rename columns of the iterations board view in TFS? How to rename default backlog?

Tags: tfs

I've been using TFS at work a lot, but now created it for my own purposes.So, my questions are:

- How to rename columns of the iterations board view (sprint view) in TFS?
- How to rename default backlog (eg Stories or Features to something else)?

I searched a lot, but haven't found any answer.
Renaming columns of the backlog board view (inside Stories - Board) is easy - just clicking on column is enough to rename it, however this doesn't work for sprint view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question 1:***

If you mean to rename the column  as below:

[image]

It's ***not able to*** rename it for now. Just as you said, you could only modify the backlog board, but not the board for iterations.

***Question 2:***

- For on-premise TFS, you need to **export** the process config, edit
  the xml to rename the Features backlog to the name you want,
  **import** the process config back.

  More detail step please take a look at this blog: [Renaming the Features Portfolio Backlog to Epics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgartner/2014/01/27/tfs-2013-renaming-the-features-portfolio-backlog-to-epics/)

  How to modify/update the `ProcessConfiguration.xml` ,you could also refer [Update ProcessConfiguration to add the Initiative portfolio backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-portfolio-backlogs?view=vsts#update-processconfig)
- For VSTS, you could rename it by customizing your backlog, how to
  please refer: [Edit, rename, or delete a portfolio backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=vsts#edit-or-rename-the-requirement-backlog)

Comment: Thanks! That's almost what I wanted.